# Can an iMessage app extension add recipients?

Tags: ios, swift, imessage, imessage-extension

When you click the new message button in the Messages app, iMessage app extensions are available, even though recipients have not yet been chosen. This makes me wonder: can the extensions themselves can add recipients?

It's not clear to me from the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/imessage/). For example, could using an extension insert a phone number into the recipients bar so the user doesn't have to?

Comment: Nope, they can mostly work with the messages created by the extension and create new messages that the user can choose to send.

Comment: Thanks @EmilioPelaez